# How to Fix "Not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have an object array that i'm returning to use the objects in a different method, however for some reason it's saying "not all code paths return a value"

Here's the code....

```
private object[] runTests(string banText, object tabControlName, int runThisTest, string testName)
    {
        if (stopTests == false)
        {
            var tabPageBrowser = new TabPage();
            var Browser = new WebBrowser();

            (tabControlName as TabControl).TabPages.Add(tabPageBrowser);
            tabPageBrowser.Name = tabControlName.ToString();
            tabPageBrowser.Text = testName;
            tabPageBrowser.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F,
                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Browser.Url = new Uri(testStrings(runThisTest, banText));
            Browser.Name = tabControlName.ToString();
            Browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            tabPageBrowser.Controls.Add(Browser);

            try
            {
                while (Browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
            SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);

            object[] browserObjects = new object[2];
            browserObjects[0] = tabPageBrowser;
            browserObjects[1] = Browser;

            if (browserObjects != null)
            {
                return browserObjects;                    
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont see what i'm doing wrong, can you please assist? Thank you!

Comment: One of the issues is the if statement around browserObjects, it can never be null but in writing the statement you create a path that doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method does not return if

stopTests == true

- or -

browserObjects == null

Comment: ...and just to clarify - every method in C# that returns a value **must** have an explicit `return` statement (or a thrown exception) at the end of every code path.

Comment: @Michael: Or an infinite loop; the compiler will treat "while(true){}" as having an unreachable end point. It is actually easier to say what you mean by phrasing it as: **the end point of a non-void method must not be reachable**.

Comment: @Eric: yes, that makes a lot of logical sense, but I'm not sure how prevalent the concept of an method's "end point" is.

Comment: @Michael: The end-point of the method is lexically the close curly brace that terminates the body; I don't think that's a particularly abstruse concept.

Comment: @Nico: No, I mean what I said. Let me re-state it. If the end point of a non-void method is reachable then the method can terminate without returning a value. It is not legal for a non-void method to terminate without returning a value, except via an exception. Therefore the end point of a non-void method must not be reachable. Is that now clear?

Comment: @Eric, ah. I didn't understand the "end point" was the closing brace tag }

Answer (score 4):

Hint: try to find a path that doesn't run through any `return`.

Answer (score 4):

Return a value in all code paths

Answer (score 2):

Getter or accessor method must always return a primitive value or an object.

In your example you are saying

```
private object[] runTests(...) // Which means that no matter what, this method must return object[] or throw an exception
```

Than you have a condition:

```
if(my_condition_is_met)
{
 do_some_processing();
}
```

Now, if condition isn't met, than you are not going to return anything, when in the first line we've said that we are going to return array of objects.

Primitive, but hopefully makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

in you code you don't have else part so here i've retrn null.

```
    if (stopTests == false) 
    {
        //your code 
    }
    else
        return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return browserObjects;
```

ditch the if statement. technically that if statement will always hit, but compiler doesn't go that deep (code contracts would go that deep though)